# prevent expanding parent node when its datasource is updated due to addition of a child item inside kendo treeview

Tags: kendo-treeview, databound

I have a kendotreeview with 3 root parent nodes.Example is shown below.
When I drop **child3** into **New SubGroup**, the node "New Subgroup" **gets expanded by default** **even if it was collapsed before**. I would like to prevent this possibility. If **New SubGroup** was expanded before, then I would like to keep it as it is. The problem is that the **expand** gets called before the **databound** event and hence I am stuck here.

Please help.

parent1:

```
--New SubGroup  
--Child2  
--Child3 
--Child4
```

parent2:

```
--Child4  
--Child5
```

```js
Code snippet:
 dataBound: function (e) {
            console.log("DataBound", e.node);
            var nodedataitem = $("#DimMeasTree").data("kendoTreeView").dataItem($(e.node));
            if (nodedataitem.FieldKey === "SubGroup" && ($(e.node).attr("aria-expanded")) === "true") {
                
                $("#DimMeasTree").data("kendoTreeView").collapse($(e.node));
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am subscribing to my own custom expand function (i.e. subgroup_expand()) after I initialize my treeview. It is as demonstrated below:

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
function subgroup_expand(e) {
   if (typeof event === 'undefined') {
        //If browser is Firefox, the subgroup will expand and do not close automatically.
        // It is because Firefox does not support "event" attribute gloabally as in IE or in Google chrome.
    }
   else if (!!e.node && typeof(event) !== 'undefined' && event.type !== "click" && event.type !== "dblclick") {
        var nodedataitem = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").dataItem($(e.node));
        if (nodedataitem.FieldKey === "SubGroup") {
            // e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(function () {
                //Collapse the subgroup if it was not expanded by click or dblclick.
                $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").collapse($(e.node));
            }, 50);
        }
    }
}
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource: modeldata
});
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
treeview.bind("expand", subgroup_expand);
</script>
```